# ASIHTTPRequest - download problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, download, asihttprequest

I try to download a file from my server, this is the code, on my console I see the xml file, but I can't save it.
Where is the problem for you?

```
- (IBAction)grabURL:(id)sender{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.endurodoc.net/photo/data.xml"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request startSynchronous];

    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (!error) {
        NSString *response = [request responseString];
        NSLog(@"%@",response);

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Errore");
    }    

    //[request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/Users/kikko/Desktop/data.xml"];

    // SAVED PDF PATH
    // Get the Document directory
    NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    // Add your filename to the directory to create your saved pdf location
    NSString *pdfLocation = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.xml"];

    // TEMPORARY PDF PATH
    // Get the Caches directory
    NSString *cachesDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    // Add your filename to the directory to create your temp pdf location
    NSString *tempPdfLocation = [cachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.xml"];

    // Tell ASIHTTPRequest where to save things:
    [request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:tempPdfLocation];     
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:pdfLocation]; 

}
```

Comment: why would you use ASIHTTPRequest if NSURLConnection can do exactly that without using any third party code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put:

```
[request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:tempPdfLocation];     
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:pdfLocation];
```

before:

```
[request startSynchronous];
```

ASIHTTPRequest does the file saving when the request is made, so if you set those properties after the request has already happened then nothing will happen.